# Use $gt and $lt with letters in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I have this collection

```
db.persone.find()

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5429b4bdd16acba384618d09"),
    "nome" : "Alessio"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5429b4bdd16acba384618d0a"),
    "nome" : "Claudia"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5429b4bdd16acba384618d0b"),
    "nome" : "Barbara"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5429b4bdd16acba384618d0c"),
    "nome" : "Marco"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5429b4bdd16acba384618d0d"),
    "nome" : "Arianna"
}
```

If I do

`db.persone.find({nome:{$gt:'A'}})` I have the same result

If i Do

`db.persone.find({nome:{$lt:'B'}})` I have this result

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5429b4bdd16acba384618d09"),
    "nome" : "Alessio"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5429b4bdd16acba384618d0d"),
    "nome" : "Arianna"
}
```

The same result i have with `$lte`.

My question is

Why with `$lt` or `$lte`, the letter 'B' isn't including like with `$gt`?

What different, in this case, to do `$gt`instead `$gte`and `$lt`instead `$lte`.

Comment: Do you always need to check the first character only? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is a decent tutorial on the subject [here](http://technotip.com/4101/string-comparison-mongodb/).

Basically, it will compare the strings lexicographically, one character at a time, and if that is indeterminate, it will compare the next character.

In your `$gt` example, the only character you're giving it to compare is `A`, but you can think of it as if there is a hidden "terminating" character that everything is greater than. So if you think of `A` with a second character, lets say `\n` (its acutally a null character \u0000, but that is harder to display), then in the comparison of `A\n` to `Alessio\n`, it will compare the `A` to `A`, be unable to determine, then move on and compare `l` to `\n` and see that `l` > `\n`, therefore it concludes that the entire string `Alessio` is greater than `A`.

Conversely, with the `$lt` operator, when its comparing `B\n` to `Barbara\n`, it will reach the comparison `a` < `\n` (remember the terminating character is always less), which evaluates to `False` and therefore `Barbara` is not less than `B`.